# Rename BitBucket repository using REST API 2.0?

Tags: rest, repository, bitbucket, rename

The only other chatter I've found about a rename-repo operation is based on the 1.0 REST API, which stopped working a year or so ago.

I should be able to use [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#put), but so far no luck: I find the "request example" confusing.

The "Note:" clearly implies that it should be possible to rename a repository using the 2.0 API. ("Note: Changing the name of the repository will cause the location to be changed.")

But a PUT to 2.0/repositories/owner/repo with data {"full_name": "owner/newname"} doesn't seem to change the name. Evidently it does locate the right repository, because I get back JSON describing that repository, but still with the original name. The web UI finds the original name, does not find the new name.

I would just like a working example of the data body to PUT to the 2.0/repositories/owner/repo path to rename owner/repo. Thanks.

(n.b. I already know how to rename a repo using the web UI. I must rename 84 repositories and would rather not do it by hand.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that {"name": "newname"} works. Attempting to change "full_name" or "slug" does not. TIL...